# Running timer every one minute in Windows Service for 24 hours?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a timer clocking every one minute in  C# window Service. And, This pc is running 24 hours and never shut down. My workflow is that user will set the time for my service to run some processes. eg. he set 14:20. So, When my timer hit 14:20, I run some sql functions. Will it be any impact on performance If i run the timer like that for 24 hours?
Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like Quartz.NET: http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/